# How to serve another repos built files from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, git, express

I have two repos:

- A Vue client interface;
- A NodeJS socket and web server.

**I need to serve the built files of the Vue interface with the server** and don't know how to proceed...

I have two ideas of how to solve this:

1. Create a script that would clone the Vue repo, build it and move the
   builded files in a folder server by the server.
2. Declare the Vue repo as a dependency of the server and find a way to
   build and access to the dependency files.

The second one seems cleaner but I don't know how to begin approaching this. Could someone please provide some thoughts on the better approach and how I might get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged git so I'm going to say use approach 2 but use git sub-modules. You could create some sort of webpack task to build your Vuejs project within the Vuejs repository. Then you can submodule your vuejs repository to the web server / socket project.

You can then use some sort of gulp or webpack script to call into the vuejs project to instruct it to build. Once that is built you can use the [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) function to serve up the build from your web server on whatever route you want (probably just the `/` route).

With submodules you can simply bump the submodule when you're ready to do a new release of the frontend and then re-deploy the web server with the new version of the dependency. This is how the [Ghost project](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost) do their frontend deployments.

Git Submodules documentation - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules.

Comment: For whom who want to learn it: https://delicious-insights.com/en/posts/mastering-git-submodules/

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it with Express:

```
const express = require("express"),
      path = require("path"),
      app = express()

const DIST_DIR = path.normalize(__dirname + "/../../VueOutputDir")

app.use(express.static(DIST_DIR))
```

This will automatically serve the `index.html` and the assets from the `VueOutputDir` directory.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to "link" the Vue repo to the server's one as the server will never run without it...

In your proposition, I'll have to clone the both repositories, to build them and to change the path to match the Vue output dir